# Lock X and Y axis of vertices in edit mode from python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I using Blender to edit terrain files that are later exported and used in my game engine. Terrain files there are planes with a fixed number of vertices with consistent spacing between them. I want to somehow be able to lock editing of X and Y coordinates of objects with some certain property on the scene. Is that possible somehow?

I came up with the idea that having a way to somehow check the execution context of bpy.ops.transform.translate would help me, since it is the operator called with specific arguments, so I just could check if X and Y coordinates are zeros, or cancel the operator. Is there any way to hook or wrap this operator?

Or is there any other ways to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

Once you start moving an object you can press <kbd>Z</kbd> to lock all motion to the z axis (preventing changes in x or y).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/axis_locking.html

Comment: I need to lock it permanently, so the user of my addon won't be able to do it. I want a fail-safe solution.